# string command fails in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am just trying to truncate the first two characters from a varchar field in Subjects.subjectid for the subset of records as specified, but it's not working. I can't spot what's wrong with my code (postgresql):

```
UPDATE subjects
SET
    subjectid = substring(S.subjectid from 2)
FROM
  ibg_studies ST,subjects S,dnasample D
WHERE 
    D.studyindex=ST.studyindex
    AND ST.studyabrv='CONGER'
    AND D.subjectidkey=S.id
    AND D.projectindex IS NULL
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: run the following and tell us what happens `SELECT  S.subjectid FROM
  ibg_studies ST,subjects S,dnasample D
WHERE 
    D.studyindex=ST.studyindex
    AND ST.studyabrv='CONGER'
    AND D.subjectidkey=S.id
    AND D.projectindex IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery is not coupled (uncorellated) to the table being updated.
I don't know what your intentions were, but maybe you want this (just guessing) :

```
UPDATE subjects sj
SET
   subjectid = substring(S.subjectid from 2) -- << what is this?
FROM
  ibg_studies st
  -- ,subjects s
  ,dnasample d
WHERE d.studyindex = st.studyindex
  AND st.studyabrv = 'CONGER'
  AND d.subjectidkey = sj.id  -- changed from s to sj?
  AND d.projectindex IS NULL
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that SQL had a problem updating a field while calling a string function on the same field. I overcame the limitation by adding a column to the table, updating this new column with the string function, then copying that new column value into the original target field, like this:

```
-- 6: copy modified subjectid to temp
--UPDATE dnasample D
--SET
--  temp = substring(S.subjectid from 3)
--FROM
--  ibg_studies ST,subjects S
--WHERE 
--  D.studyindex=ST.studyindex
--  AND ST.studyabrv='CONGER'
--  AND D.subjectidkey=S.id
--  AND D.projectindex IS NULL

-- 7: copy temp to subjectid
--UPDATE subjects S
--SET
--  subjectid = D.temp
--FROM
--  ibg_studies ST,dnasample D
--WHERE 
--  D.studyindex=ST.studyindex
--  AND ST.studyabrv='CONGER'
--  AND D.subjectidkey=S.id
--  AND D.projectindex IS NULL

-- 8: Remove the temp column
ALTER TABLE dnasample DROP COLUMN temp
```

Comment: Note: I would manually add or remove the SQL comment operator -- and then rerun the script. I only wanted one SQL command running at a time, so that I could inspect the results of each command.